# find diagonal of a triangle?

Tags: iphone, math

I'm trying to basically code:

```
double squared(diagonal) = a(squared) + b(squared);
```

Can anyone help me put this in code? Couldn't really find what I was looking for...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
double diagonal = sqrt(a * a + b * b);
```

Comment: `hypot()` IS the function to use! Read man page: "_The hypot() function computes the sqrt(x*x+y*y) without undue overflow or underflow._" It is also faster :)

Answer (score 5):

Just use straight-up C:

```
double diagonal = sqrt(a*a + b*b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [hypot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypot), which is available for several languages, including C99:

```
double diagonal = hypot(a,b);
```